# create an hashmap from an arraylist of objects and attach map marker to them

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

i have the following problem:

i have an arraylist of objects that i wish to create markers for and fill some data for an info window for each marker.

```
private ArrayList<Ad> _items = new ArrayList<Ad>();
```

which is filled from a a db containing that info.

i am kind of new to java and android development so i am alittle puzzled on finding a solution.

i was thinking of creating a `HashMap<Marker , Ad>`

but i really dont know if that is the best solution, or how to implement it.

any ideas?

thank you.

Comment: Add marker in for  loop of your array list of hasmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on a Map app at the moment, and the best solution which I have implemented is:

1) Create a AsyncTask which does the following:
  a) Retrieves data from your database - eg. Location, Icon, Name, Snipper, etc
  b) Then creates the Marker

c) Adds the marker.

What all of this will do is create a new Worker Thread (which runs in the background- separate from your UI thread) so if you have a large database and need to add 100's if not 1000's of markers, it could take a few minutes and you don't want to perform this on your UI thread as it will be blocked.

Let me know if you need help.

**EDIT**

In your **Activity**, call the new Task like this:

You can pass as many paramaters to the AsyncTask as you need. They can be any type of objects. Eg. Strings, int, Map.

for "map" pass your `GoogleMap map = (GoogleMap) findViewById(...);` reference to it

```
new AddMarkersAsyncTask(getApplicationContext()).execute(map, param1, param2, etc...);
```

Your AsyncTask should look something like this: **AddMarkersAsyncTask.class**

```
public class AddMarkersAsyncTask  extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {

    static Context mContext;

    public AddMarkersAsyncTask(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {

        // Here you retrieve all the params like this
        // You will need to add Cast to each param as they are all passed as generic object.
        GoogleMap map = (GoogleMap) params[0];
        String[] a = (String[]) params[1];
        int airport_marker_w = (Integer) params[2];
        int airport_marker_h = (Integer) params[3];
        ... etc etc

        // Here retrieve all your database data

        String tile = "Title";
        String snippet = "Snippet";
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeFromResource(R.drawable.my_marker);
        LatLnt position = <SomePosition>;

        // If your array list or length of markers is say 50 markers, do a for loop with either i < listname.length or i < listname.size() or i < 50, etc etc

        for(int i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
            new AddMarker(mContext).addMarker(map, title, snippet, icon, position);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

then create another class AddMarker: **AddMarker.class**

```
public class AddMarker {

    static Context mContext;
    public AddMarker(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public int addMarker(final GoogleMap map,String title, String snippet, Bitmap icon) {
        final MarkerOptions opts = new MarkerOptions();
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        opts.title(title);
        opts.snippet(snippet);
        opts.position(position);
        opts.icon(icon);
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                map.addMarker(opts);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this give you an idea of what to do :)
Let me know if you need more help

Comment: that is a good suggestion and i will definetly do so. how ever, I need an example for creating the markers and setting the infowindow with the respective data...

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to "Accept" answers if your question is answered so that it can be ticked off.

Comment: i will, but i need some more assistance. can you demonstrate how to create the markers and set the info window dynamicly from the arraylist?

Comment: thank you for your reply, however, i was unable to implement it for now... i think i'm gonna wait until my skills improve alittle

Comment: Why couldn't you? Need help?